# Clarity on the scope of a data analyst and data scientist

Tags: data

I am new to the field of data analyst and I need clarity on the scope of work it covers.

Say there's a dataset consisting of reps and weights of free weights lifted by a group of users over time and we want to build a 1 rep max recommendation for them. The system will recommend a user's 1 rep max value based on his workouts over time. It's evident that a formula is needed to compute this 1 rep max and much research is required to justify the approach in deriving that formula.

I sense that the scope of work involve 2 parties: Data Analyst and Data Scientist. Can someone enlighten me at which part of development does individual role come in?

P.S. Perhaps my question is not at the right place and if so kindly enlighten me.